# Как обозначить pictureBox на переднем плане?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Проблема в том, что при повторном запуске приложения (с защитой от повторного запуска), каким-то образом теряются правила расположения pictureBox, и некоторые изображения которые должны быть на переднем плане, оказываются на заднем плане.

На данный момент pictureBox только отображается, без определения позиции:

```
pictureBox1.Visible = true;
```

Вроде как решение есть, но не совсем понятно как его использовать:

```
Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
pictureBox1.BringToFront();
```

Обязательно ли использовать `Controls.Add()` и для чего это нужно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необязательно. Добавьте в конструктор формы:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.BringToFront();        
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, еще помогает строчка `pictureBox1.BringToFront();` под основной строкой `pictureBox1.Visible = true;`